# Onclick simple program giving logic error ( 'Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied')

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I am getting the error 'Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied' which I know has somthing to do with error in the logic; the issue is my xml files are spic and span, therefore I assume it must be by activity class.

I have a main layout (main.xml) which has the buttons: 'start' and 'instructions'. When clicking the instructions button it should go to the layout: instructions.xml and when clicking the start button it should go to the layout: test_layout.xml.

For any insight what so ever I would be most grateful and pour millions of reputation on you. Thanks.

-Is the issue that I am implementing the OnClickListener ?

-Is it something to do not putting a @Override on top of the second method ('public void onClick')? because it says that I can only place it when overwriting a super class.**

Please, it very short code, I could appreciate if you could take a quick glance and tell me what you think. I posted the manifest bellow the code.

```
package it.will.work;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



public class ActualWorkingQuizActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


 Button start = (Button) findViewById(it.will.work.R.id.start_main);
 Button instructions = (Button) findViewById(it.will.work.R.id.instructions_main);


    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


     //sets the Click Listeners
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    instructions.setOnClickListener(this); 

}

public void onClick(View v) {
     if (v==start) {
         setContentView(it.will.work.R.layout.test_layout);
     }
     else if (v==instructions) {
         setContentView(it.will.work.R.layout.instructions);
}
     }
     }
```

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="it.will.work"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/starwarsicon"
       android:label="@string/appname" >
       <activity
           android:label="@string/appname"
           android:name=".ActualWorkingQuizActivity" >
           <intent-filter >
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
```

Comment: Is the debugging option ticked in run configuration?

Comment: This message does not reflect the error in your program which caused it to crash, rather it reflects a bug in the error reporting code.  When you solve the problem causing your program to crash, you'll stop triggering the reporting code and stop hitting this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your Buttons in onCreate().

```
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_main);
instructions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.instructions_main);
```

In onClick() method make changes like this

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.start_main)
    {
      setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.instructions_main)
    {
      setContentView(R.layout.instructions);
    }
}
```

Or Alternate

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (v.equals(start))
    {
      setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
    } else if (v.equals(instructions))
    {
      setContentView(R.layout.instructions);
    }
}
```

Comment: It didnt change anything because the:                                   'Button start = (Button) findViewById(it.will.work.R.id.start_main);
Button instructions = (Button) findViewById(it.will.work.R.id.instructions_main);'

Comment: Same error:'Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied'. Do you have any other ideas, should I replace my format with one of your alternatives even though it still shows error, what was wrong with using the = operator. Thanks, also if you have another solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: Using == compares the references. 
object.equals() on the other hand compares the values

Comment: I can't figure out what else I'm doing wrong, I could implement this using the inline way but I'd rather do this so in the future I can add more buttons, ect.